# how to extract consecutive pattern using bash script

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I tried awk,grep and sed to parse the consecutive pattern as per below output but the result is null. only either of the pattern is working.

The `awk '/^[0-9]/ && /OAA-/' file.txt`  and  `grep -E '^[0-9].*ORA-' file.txt`

The below input

```
    2021-04-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
    OCC(3):
    OCC(3):DB initialized.
    OAA-06512: at "PATCH", line 001
    2021-05-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
    OAA-06513: at "PATCH", line 002
    OAA-06514: at "PATCH", line 003
    2021-06-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
    This is the empty string.
```

Expected output

```
2021-04-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
OAA-06512: at "PATCH", line 001

2021-05-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
OAA-06513: at "PATCH", line 002
OAA-06514: at "PATCH", line 003
```

Could provide the syntax to parse the consecutive pattern like Date followed by OAA comment as per the expected output.

Comment: Maybe `grep -E '^([0-9]|OAA-)' file.txt` will do?

Comment: @DevopsDevelop : Both (your awk and grep) pattern search for lines which start with a digit, and have the string _OAA_ somewhere. I don't see how this would match your expected output.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for the update. I have edited the input file content. the expected output is only the time stamp and line start with OAA-. your code parses all the time stamp.

Comment: @DevopsDevelop, does that space in your shown input sample is really present in your Input file please confirm once?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, updated the input. pls have a look. the expected output is timestamp with OAA- but other timestamp and other lines can be removed. pls validate the output.

Comment: Your recent edit completely changed your input and output formats. Is what's currently posted 100% accurate now, including the blanks at the start of every input line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '/^OAA-/ {if (dt) print "\n" dt; print; dt=""} /[0-9]{4}-/ {dt=$0} ' file

2021-04-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
OAA-06512: at "PATCH", line 001

2021-05-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
OAA-06513: at "PATCH", line 002
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, seems the script can parse one OAA- line. if we have multiple OAA- lines below the time stamp how do we declare the syntax. updated the expected output. kindly have a look.

Comment: The command is working. Anubhava, while exporting the output to the text format, the space is lost but the space between time stamp is visible in the linux command shell. kindly advise.

Comment: Redirect output to a file using `awk '/^OAA-/ {if (dt) print "\n" dt; print; dt=""} /[0-9]{4}-/ {dt=$0} ' file > file.out`

Answer (score 5):

With the example you posted you don't need to grep for anything you can just do:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '{print $1 ORS $NF}' file
2021-04-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
OAA-06512: at "PATCH", line 001
2021-05-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00
OAA-06513: at "PATCH", line 002
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to provide a better example including cases where that doesn't work.

Comment: answering a question with awk leads to more questions   =)

Comment: @CalvinTaylor not sure where you're coming from with that statement. Do you have a specific question in mind that a basic understanding of awk or a couple of minutes reading the awk man page wouldn't answer?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts/samples, please try following once, trying to fix OP's attempts here.

```
awk 'sub(/^ +/,"") && /^([0-9]|OAA-)/' Input_file
```

Simply edited conditions of OP's checks here. Checking conditions, if line starts from digits OR OAA- then print that line.

Comment: Hiya, updated the input file above. your code parses all the timestamps. any syntax to parse the timestamp with OAA- sequence but remove other file contents. The input and the expected output has been updated. kindly validate.

Comment: @DevopsDevelop, Could you please try `awk 'sub(/^ +/,"") && /^([0-9]|OAA-)/'  Input_file` once and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Ravi, the syntax is wrong, the sub function prints empty value.

Comment: @DevopsDevelop, This is a tested command, do let me know what error you are getting here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use "or", not "and":
`awk '/^[0-9]/ || /^OAA/' input-file`.
This will match lines starting with a number or with the string "OAA".

The extract of the file you show is very small, but if the lines are all like your sample, a simple `grep -v OCC input-file` could do it, however it may not lead to the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to run with perl regex syntax with grep a lot as I find it easier as I know it.

```
grep -P '(?:^\d|^OAA-)' file.txt
```

So we are searching file.txt for lines starting with a number or starting wtih OAA.   The '(?' denotes the start of a non capturing group, used because we want to make use of the OR character, '|', and closed by the trailing bracket ')'

Comment: `'(?:^\d|^OAA-)'` = `'^\d|^OAA-'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, getting additional line as below

`2021-05-27T05:30:13.292507-04:00`

Comment: @DevopsDevelop Right, that is why I did not post this solution (this one is identical to the one in my top comment below the question).

Comment: The logic can be to parse the timestamp preceding to the line starts with OAA-. so that the expected output will match as updated in the post.